# Find out a CHECKBOX in a DATAGRID in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I have a GRIDVIEW and with several CHECKBOXS.

When i selected a CHECKBOX I need run some code.

To detect it, I use an EVENT HANDLER for the CHECKBOX included in a GRIDVIEW.

I cannot access the CHECKBOX with my wrong code.

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks for your help. Bye

### ASPX

```
    <asp:Label ID="uxMessageDisplayer" runat="server" Visible="False" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label>
<asp:GridView ID="uxUserListDisplayer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    OnRowDataBound="uxUserListDisplayer_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="uxActiveCheckBoxSelector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="uxRoleCheckBoxSelector_CheckChanged" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Users">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="uxUserNameLabelDisplayer" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="uxLinkEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                    Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="uxLinkDeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete"
                    Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### CODE BEHIND

```
    protected void uxRoleCheckBoxSelector_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // Reference the CheckBox that raised this event   
        //CheckBox uxActiveCheckBoxSelector = sender as CheckBox;

        CheckBox activeCheckBox = (CheckBox)FindControl("uxActiveCheckBoxSelector");

        if (activeCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            uxMessageDisplayer.Text = "T - Aproved User";
            uxMessageDisplayer.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            uxMessageDisplayer.Text = "F - NOT Aproved User";
            uxMessageDisplayer.Enabled = false;
        }
       }
```

Comment: Where are you registering the checkbox-checked-event? Show us some code either from the aspx or from the gridview's rowdatabound. Normally the sender is the checkbox which fires that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the event handler is actually registered to the checkbox.

```
CheckBox activeCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
```

what is `"uxActiveCheckBoxSelector"` and why are you ignoring `sender`?

Comment: uxActiveCheckBoxSelector is the CHECKBOX I need to FINDOUT; could you please send me an example of code I do not understand I am a beginner :-)

Comment: The sender parameter is the object that triggered the event, in this case, it would be the checkbox you're "looking for"

Comment: @GibboK for the code you've provided, you need to swap out `CheckBox activeCheckBox = (CheckBox)FindControl("uxActiveCheckBoxSelector");` for the statement in my answer. the `Label` you're accessing is outside the grid, so you can access it directly.

Answer (score 2):

If I am not mistaken by your question, you are trying to set the text of the label on the same row with the `checkbox` based on its checked status.

Below is the code snippet I tried on my pc, hope it helps.

**.aspx:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
        return;

    //create dummy data
    List<string> rows = new List<string>();
    Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList().ForEach(x => rows.Add(x.ToString()));

    //bind dummy data to gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = rows;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

    protected void CheckBox1_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //cast sender to checkbox
        CheckBox CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)sender;

        //retrieve the row where checkbox is contained
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)CheckBox1.NamingContainer;

        //find the label in the same row
        Label Label1 = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");

        //logics
        if (CheckBox1 != null)  //make sure checkbox1 is found
        {
            if (CheckBox1.Checked)
            {
                if (Label1 != null) //make sure label1 is found
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Checked";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                if (Label1 != null)
                {
                    Label1.Text = "Unchecked";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Code corrected as suggest!
[Usefull resource for beginners](http://forums.asp.net/p/1318957/2616392.aspx)

```
        protected void uxRoleCheckBoxSelector_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cast sender to CheckBox
        CheckBox activeCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;

        // Retrieve the row where CheckBox is contained (NamingContainer used to retrive parent control
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)activeCheckBox.NamingContainer;

        if (activeCheckBox.Checked == true)
        {
            uxMessageDisplayer.Text = "T - Aproved User";
        }
        else
        {
            uxMessageDisplayer.Text = "F - NOT Aproved User";
        }
    }
```